# Async design: Push from mySQL to web tier?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, design-patterns, asynchronous

I am trying to build a chat-based mobile application with jQuery/AJAX, PHP, and mySQL. I don't want the client mobile device to have to poll the PHP script on the server every second to check if a new chat message has arrived, so I have used a "long polling" paradigm with AJAX to keep the connection open longer and achieve more of a push-style architecture. Below is PHP code on the server:

```
$newMessage = CheckForNewMessage();
while ($newMessage == NULL) {
  usleep(10000);
  $newMessage = CheckForNewMessage();
}
$response = array();
$response['msg'] = $newMessage;
echo json_encode($response);
```

However, as written, this PHP code polls the mySQL DBMS fairly regularly (still a pull paradigm). I am wondering if there is a way to achieve a push paradigm on *this* connection (i.e., between the web tier and the data tier). Can I use triggers when a new message is added to a table, or something similar to achieve this? Has anyone any experience in doing this? Any pointers or ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in theory one can write a [user-defined function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-udf.html) that will act as a trigger on some DB action, and (via sockets) call some external PHP script.

But then, I think, you'll still have a conflict: how should this PHP script interact with your code? The problem is that your architecture is still 'pull'-oriented: only this time pulls are conducted in some periodic timeframe.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is just unsuitable for this kind of communication. Even with MS SQL which does support push notifications I would still consider using it a mistake. Relational Database are used to **store** data. Not **dispatch**.

I would suggest using some XMPP server or (if not possible) message queues instead of MySQL. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.msg-get-queue.php for the start.